# Changing Serial Number in pagination

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

I am using this code for serial numbers in my table with pagination:

```
$number = 1
echo "<td>  ". $number++ ." </td>";
```

But the problem is, When i change the page number, it starts from 1 again.

I am using `"?page=x"` for pagination.

So, if i have 5 records in ?page=1, then the serial number should start from 6 in page number 2.

How to make it do so?

I cannot use unique id from MySQL, because, i deleted some of my records in between, and the unique id numbers are something like this "1,2,3,5,6,8,10"

Comment: I don't know what you mean about `unique id`s.

Comment: That does not matter. Do your query and use limit. `SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 5,10` for page 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$number = 1;
$numElementsPerPage = 5; // How many elements per page
$pageNumber = isset($_GET['page']) ? (int)$_GET['page'] : 1;
$currentNumber = ($pageNumber - 1) * $numElementsPerPage + $number;
echo "<td>  ". $currentNumber++ ." </td>";
$number++;
```

Comment: Worked, btw we do not need to increment $number, at the end. It do nothing

Comment: Yes, I assumed that this was part of a for or while loop, that is why I kept the ++ part :)